How to connect a NestJS + Prisma API to an external database?
I'm trying to connect my NestJS + Prisma API to an external database to fetch its data. How can I achieve this?
For context, I already have a primary database that manages the data for the API itself. However, I need to connect to another database in order to create a specific route where the data exists only in that external database.
What's the best way to do this? I've tried using two schemas, but I couldn't get it working.
The application only recognizes the schema that i created when trying to fit this. The command that i'm using is npx prisma generate --schema=prisma/external-database/schema.prisma. The schema from my main database is overwritten by the external schema.
UPDATE:
Ok, I finally managed to get both schemas working correctly, but I'm encountering an issue when importing the PrismaClient from the external schema:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../../../prisma/*****/external-base/index.js'

The import works fine when I use the absolute path:
import { PrismaClient } from 'C:\Users\adria\projects\****\******-api\prisma\**\external-database';

However, when I try using the relative path (as shown in the example above), the error persists. Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this or how I can fix it?
